# How a command is created and added to the path in a python repo

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, pip

I am working on a git repo https://opendev.org/airship/promenade
it creates a image promenade  on a base python image.
inside the image it creates an executable /usr/local/bin/promenade which is a python script and is the main command on which the image runs .
I want to understand how this image added /usr/local/bin/promenade as executable and how it is calling other modules
any help will be appreciated , i have gone through all basics of setup.py and pip install but could not figure this out

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#console-scripts -- https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#automatic-script-creation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very typical setup for Docker containers is to use a language runtime's native packaging tools, and then do the minimum necessary in a `Dockerfile` to install the application using this.  That's what's happening here.

The core of the [Python packaging environment](https://packaging.python.org) is a script, `setup.py`, that describes how to install the package.  In this repository the [`setup.py`](https://opendev.org/airship/promenade/src/branch/master/setup.py) uses a package called [pbr](https://docs.openstack.org/pbr/latest/) that moves most of the setup to a non-code configuration file, [`setup.cfg`](https://opendev.org/airship/promenade/src/branch/master/setup.cfg).  That contains a block:

```ini
[entry_points]
console_scripts =
    promenade=promenade.cli:promenade
```

The [`console_scripts`](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#console-scripts) is a standard part of the Python `setuptools` library.  When you run `pip install` (or `./setup.py install`) it creates a wrapper script named `promenade` in the `bin` directory of the current installation.  That script just starts Python, imports the `promenade.cli` module, and calls the `promenade()` function in it.

If you have a local checkout of this, you can see this using a Python virtual environment:

```sh
# Create a new virtual environment
python3 -m venv venv

# Install this package in that virtual environment
./venv/bin/pip install .

# See the new wrapper script
ls -l ./venv/bin/promenade
```

In a Docker context, you don't generally use a virtual environment: the Docker image is isolated from the host system, and generally only a single application is installed in an image, so there's no conflicts if you're using the "system" python.  The [`Dockerfile`](https://opendev.org/airship/promenade/src/branch/master/Dockerfile) in that repository in fact just runs `pip`:

```sh
COPY . /opt/promenade
RUN pip install -e /opt/promenade
```

Absent a virtual environment, `pip install` for the system python will generally install these console scripts in `/usr/local/bin`, so this last line will create the `/usr/local/bin/promenade` wrapper.

Comment: Thanks David thats the answer I was looking for , a lot of searching in google could not have given this explanation , thanks a lot